# Need help under standing the definition of the Weyl Algebra, $A_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, algebras

From the source I'm reading (S. C. Coutinho, A Primer of Algebraic D-Modules), $A_n$ is defined to be the subalgebra of $\text{End}(\mathbb{C}[x_1,..., x_n])$ generated by the operator $$x_i : \mathbb{C}[x_1,..., x_n]\to \mathbb{C}[x_1,..., x_n]$$ given by multiplication with $x_i$, i.e., $$x_i(f(x_1,...,x_n))=x_i \cdot f(x_1,....,x_n)$$ and the operator $$\partial_i:\mathbb{C}[x_1,..., x_n]\to \mathbb{C}[x_1,..., x_n]$$ given by $$\partial_i(f(x_1,...,x_n))=\partial f(x_1,...,x_n)/\partial x_i,$$ subject to the relation $$\partial_i x_i-x_i\partial_i=I,$$ where $I$ is the identity operator.

Elsewhere, I have read that this algebra may be thought of
as the algebra of linear differential operators with polynomial coefficients.

Questions: (1) How are these two definitions equivalent?

(2) Are we are also defining some kind of action of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,..., x_n]$ on $A_n$, or is there an inclusion because then it would make sense how the coefficients are coming about.

Comment: How is it defined the algebra of linear differential operators with polynomial coefficients?

Comment: @jijijojo Not *defined* that way exactly, but it is said (see link, page 1) that it can be thought of as such. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204303.pdf

Comment: I myself want to know what they mean by it. I've seen the exact same sentence in many places but no one explains what they mean by that. That is said, the claimed 'identification' is irrelevant in this particular paper, as the author didn't use it to prove  any of his results.

Comment: @jijijojo: Oh, I misunderstood your first comment and thought you were challenging my assertion that it also being described that way in the literature so I pointed to that paper as an example. I am not reading that paper. However, I'm going to contact the author and ask him this question. Hopefully he'll have an answer.

Comment: @jijijojo: I believe I have found the answer to my question and you can read about it  in [1, pg. 57] if you're interested also. [1] https://books.google.lu/books?id=MU2BhyuZZp0C&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=%22weyl+algebra%22+%22polynomial+coefficients%22&source=bl&ots=XGWydcf8Uy&sig=ACfU3U09cjzRvGYyQtVS-zgdOCYV9FbT-A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi10vWy7I_qAhUB5aYKHUXsAIg4ChDoATACegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=%22weyl%20algebra%22%20%22polynomial%20coefficients%22&f=false

Comment: Great finding! I would have never thought I'll find the answer in a differential equations book. Thanks a lot for sharing!